# Linux Kernel Examination in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, kernel

I want to examine the Linux kernel source code using Visual Studio on Windows. But I don't know how to do that. Do I need a virtual machine to run or debug the kernel or is there any special way for me to do that ???

Comment: @Niels: why did you remove the name of the poster? And to the original poster: please rather edit your profile to show your name, etc ... (eg web page).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch see [policy on thanks, taglines and greeting on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 1):

What does "kernel examination" means to you?

Why can't you more simply study the source code of the Linux kernel?

It is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), you cant fetch its source code from [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/)

<sup>it is extremely likely that your Linux vendor publishes either the source code of his variant of Linux kernel, or patches against vanilla kernel source code. The [GPLv2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPLv2) license of the Linux kernel nearly requires such a behavior.</sup>

And a Linux system gives you a lot of tools (`objdump`, ....) to study ELF executable image (like the Linux kernel mostly is....)

You probably won't be able to compile the Linux kernel with Visual Studio. You need [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (or a very compatible compiler). Linux source code uses many GCC extensions.

My advice is to install a Linux system on your development machine (you can have a dual boot if you want to keep Windows for games....) and to learn it and to use Linux tools (including `emacs`, `grep`, `etags` etc....) to study the source code of Linux. Remember that Linux is the preferred platform to build the Linux kernel... (if your distribution is Debian or Ubuntu or similar, learn about `make-kpkg`)

Also read some good books about [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and about the Linux kernel (there are many of them).

BTW, you could even customize your GCC compiler, e.g. with a plugin or a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension, to measure, search, or even refactor the source code of the kernel. See also [cocinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/).

Comment: I absolutely recommend setting up a Linux installation (or at least some variant of *nix) for kernel development. You'll find kernel development on Windows a major pain in the neck.